# Youtube API client error cannot resolve host

Tags: php, youtube-api

Wow.  Earlier today I was getting

```
A client error occurred: Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google_Client/00
```

Now I'm getting

```
A client error occurred: HTTP Error: (0) Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com'
```

I am using the PHP Youtube API on Google's documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search).

I don't know what's going wrong; I have almost exactly the same code.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your server ... is it able to resolve other hosts? Do you have sufficient disk space?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two errors here, and I suspect they are issues with your server or network:

1. Verify that whatever account is executing PHP has the right permissions. /tmp should be writable by all, but there might be something weird going on. As jlmcdonald suggests, check for space.
2. From your server, verify that you have connectivity. This could be any number of reasons: DNS issues or general connectivity. You can troubleshoot these by SSHing into your server and running:

## Checks for DNS issues

```
nslookup googleapis.com
```

## Checks for general connectivity

```
ping googleapis.com
```

## This shouldn't be necessary, but checks to see if your server can even open an outbound socket on that port (ping = ICMP)

```
telnet www.googleapis.com 443
```