# Upload a video in my YouTube channel using PHP api

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I follow as explained youtube API
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video

below is my code

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '**************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '**************';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "H:/works/xampp/htdocs/youapi/test.mp4";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting following error

> An client error occurred: Could not resolve host:
>   www.googleapis.comupload

where was my mistake ? how can I solve this error ? could you please help me out

Comment: Have you included all steps required [before starting](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) development using Youtube API?

Comment: Yes, I followed @Mr.Rebot

Comment: i have the same issue ... can you please help me @Siddhu

Comment: i DONE THIS, YOU SHOULD ALWAYS LOGIN IN YOUR GMAIL ACCOUNT. FOR THAT YOU SHOULD MAKE ONE TEMPORARY TOKEN KEY FORM GOOGLE

Answer (score -1):

There seem to be two errors here, and I suspect they are issues with your server or network:

1.Verify that whatever account is executing PHP has the right permissions. /tmp should be writable by all, but there might be something weird going on. As jlmcdonald suggests, check for space.
2.From your server, verify that you have connectivity. This could be any number of reasons: DNS issues or general connectivity. You can troubleshoot these by SSHing into your server and running:
Checks for DNS issues

nslookup googleapis.com
Checks for general connectivity

ping googleapis.com
This shouldn't be necessary, but checks to see if your server can even open an outbound socket on that port (ping = ICMP)

Comment: I already done @kishan and I known this answer at my research http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287586/youtube-api-client-error-cannot-resolve-host